# Lock-free SPSC queue implementation on ARM

Tags: c++, arm, synchronization, lock-free, memory-barriers

I'm trying to write a single producer single consumer queue for ARM and I think I'm close to wrapping my head around DMB, but need some checking (I'm more familiar with std::atomic.)

Here's where I'm at:

```
bool push(const_reference value)
{
    // Check for room
    const size_type currentTail = tail;
    const size_type nextTail = increment(currentTail);
    if (nextTail == head)
        return false;

    // Write the value
    valueArr[currentTail] = value;

    // Prevent the consumer from seeing the incremented tail before the
    // value is written.
    __DMB();

    // Increment tail
    tail = nextTail;

    return true;
}

bool pop(reference valueLocation)
{
    // Check for data
    const size_type currentHead = head;
    if (currentHead == tail)
        return false;

    // Write the value.
    valueLocation = valueArr[currentHead];

    // Prevent the producer from seeing the incremented head before the
    // value is written.
    __DMB();

    // Increment the head
    head = increment(head);

    return true;
}
```

My question is: is my DMB placement and justification accurate? Or is there still understanding that I'm missing? I'm particularly uncertain about whether the conditionals need some guard when dealing with the variable that's updated by the other thread (or interrupt).

Comment: Yes, barrier then store = release-store of `tail`, and load then barrier = acquire load.  But you're using the loaded value *before* you barrier on it, for a compare-and-branch based on the value from the other thread.  You might be better off putting the DMB after the branch, before using `currentHead` / `Tail`, because you don't have a data dependency for `mo_consume` style dependency ordering.  I'm not sure if that's a problem or not.

Comment: Generally it's better to let std::atomic emit `dmb` for you, instead of using compile-time + run-time memory barriers, but for ARM you could end up with wasted barriers; you might only need one total in pop if you only need acquire ordering?  No, you might need both acquire on `tail` and release on `head`.  Note that `head = increment(head)` could use `increment(currentHead)` ; no need to reload the shared variable because this thread is the only one modifying it (SPSC).

Comment: Yeah, I would love to use std::atomic and let it emit the DMB, but I was unsure about support for it. I'm testing on an ST device so I emailed them but didn't get a clear answer. I might still try it and check the assembly.

Comment: Good point about re-using currentHead. So are you thinking a second DMB is required after the condition in both functions?

Comment: I think it so.  The possible failure mode is that `push` doesn't check `nextTail == head` until after storing to `valueArr[currentTail]` (when out-of-order speculative exec gets around to loading `tail` and verifying the predicted path).  So it could maybe step on a value that `pop` isn't done reading.  You could probably avoid that with `consume`-style ordering if you wrote the whole function in asm if you used a predicated load or store, predicated on the compare condition instead of a branch.  But in C you don't have control over whether it's a data dependency or a control dependency.

Comment: Of course if this is a single-core device then you don't need any runtime barriers, just compiler barriers (`atomic_signal_fence()` or `asm("" ::: "memory");` ). Context switches and interrupts will run on the same core, which preserves the illusion of all instructions running in program order.

Comment: Oh really? I didn't know that, thanks for mentioning it. I assumed that memory reordering was still a possibility with regards to interrupts. This will be on a single-core device, so I would then only need to worry about compiler reordering. In that case, would I replace the DMBs with compiler barriers, then add those other compiler barriers to prevent speculative reordering at the condition? Also, do you happen to know an ARM command that acts as a compiler barrier without the runtime effects?

Comment: A compiler barrier compiles to zero asm instructions.  You don't need an ARM instruction (if that's what you mean by "command"), just a C function / builtin like GNU C `asm("" ::: "memory")`.  I'd recommend hiding it behind a macro like `barrier()` so you can redefine it to include a runtime barrier if you have a future need for, like the Linux kernel does: non-SMP builds can define barrier macros to just block compile-time reordering.

Comment: Awesome, understood. Now I'm using the compiler barrier macro you mentioned, thanks for that. To wrap everything up, does this change any of the logic about where the barriers should be placed, or do the 2 barriers per function (1 to prevent speculative reordering, 1 to prevent reordering the write/increment lines) still make sense?

Comment: Yes, definitely use 2 per function to give you an acquire load and a release store bracketing the access to the array.  No need to try to justify using only one; it would only be safe if the compiler put the instructions in the desired order anyway, and blocking compile-time reordering with a compiler barrier is basically free since you already need one barrier (so code that inlines this already has to spill/reload any globals or escaped locals).  Just like I said optimize `increment(head)` to `increment(currentHead)` to avoid a pointless reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A barrier there is necessary but not sufficient, you also need "acquire" semantics for loading the var modified by the other thread.  (Or at least `consume`, but getting that without a barrier would require asm to create a data dependency.  A compiler wouldn't do that after already having a control dependency.)
- A single-core system can use just a compiler barrier like GNU C `asm("":::"memory")` or `std::atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_release)`, not `dmb`.  Make a macro so you can choose between SMP-safe barriers or UP (uniprocessor) barriers.
- `head = increment(head);` is a pointless reload of `head`, use the local copy.
- use `std::atomic` to get the necessary code-gen portably.

---

You normally don't need to roll your own atomics; modern compilers for ARM do implement `std::atomic<T>`.  But AFAIK, no `std::atomic<>` implementations are aware of single-core systems to avoid actual barriers and just be safe wrt. interrupts that can cause a context switch.

On a single-core system, you don't need `dsb`, just a compiler barrier.  The CPU will preserve the illusion of asm instructions executing sequentially, in program order.  You just need to make sure the compiler generates asm that does things in the right order.  You can do that by using `std::atomic` with `std::memory_order_relaxed`, and manual `atomic_signal_fence(memory_order_acquire)` or `release` barriers.  (Not `atomic_thread_fence`; that would emit asm instructions, typically `dsb`).

---

Each thread reads a variable that the other thread modifies.  You're correctly making the modifications release-stores by making sure they're visible only after access to the array.

**But those reads also need to be [acquire-loads](https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/) to sync with those release stores**.  E.g. to make sure `push` isn't writing `valueArr[currentTail] = value;` before `pop` finishes reading that same element.  Or reading an entry before it's fully written.

Without any barrier, the failure mode would be that `if (currentHead == tail) return false;` doesn't actually check the value of `tail` from memory until after 
`valueLocation = valueArr[currentHead];` happens.  Runtime load reordering can easily do that on weakly-ordered ARM.  If the load address had a data dependency on `tail`, that could avoid needing a barrier there on an SMP system (ARM guarantees dependency ordering in asm; the feature that `mo_consume` was supposed to expose).  But if the compiler just emits a branch, that's only a control dependency, not data.  If you were writing by hand in asm, a predicated load like `ldrne r0, [r1, r2]` on flags set by the compare would I think create a *data* dependency.

Compile-time reordering is less plausible, but a compiler-only barrier is free if it's only stopping the compiler from doing something it wasn't going to do anyway.

---

### untested implementation, compiles to asm that looks ok but no other testing

Do something similar for `push`.  I included wrapper functions for load acquire / store release, and fullbarrier().  (Equivalent of Linux kernel's `smp_mb()` macro, defined as a compile time or compile+runtime barrier.)

```
#include <atomic>

#define UNIPROCESSOR


#ifdef UNIPROCESSOR
#define fullbarrier()  asm("":::"memory")   // GNU C compiler barrier
                          // atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)
#else
#define fullbarrier() __DMB()    // or atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)
#endif

template <class T>
T load_acquire(std::atomic<T> &x) {
#ifdef UNIPROCESSOR
    T tmp = x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    // or fullbarrier();  if you want to use that macro
    return tmp;
#else
    return x.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    // fullbarrier() / __DMB();
#endif
}

template <class T>
void store_release(std::atomic<T> &x, T val) {
#ifdef UNIPROCESSOR
    std::atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_release);
    // or fullbarrier();
    x.store(val, std::memory_order_relaxed);
#else
    // fullbarrier() / __DMB(); before plain store
    return x.store(val, std::memory_order_release);
#endif
}

template <class T>
struct SPSC_queue {
  using size_type = unsigned;
  using value_type = T;
  static const size_type size = 1024;

  std::atomic<size_type> head;
  value_type valueArr[size];
  std::atomic<size_type> tail;  // in a separate cache-line from head to reduce contention

  bool push(const value_type &value)
  {
    // Check for room
    const size_type currentTail = tail.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);  // no other writers to tail, no ordering needed
    const size_type nextTail = currentTail + 1;    // modulo separately so empty and full are distinguishable.
    if (nextTail == load_acquire(head))
        return false;

    valueArr[currentTail % size] = value;
    store_release(tail, nextTail);
    return true;
  }
};

// instantiate the template for  int  so we can look at the asm
template bool SPSC_queue<int>::push(const value_type &value);
```

Compiles cleanly [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEADZJpLegAyeWpgByxgEaZi5ywAdUCwuto9QxNPUh8/NTo7B2cjNw8LRWVMVQCGAmZiAiDjU04klUjadMyCaKdXd0EFDKyckPya0vLY%2BK4ASkVUA2JkDgByKQBme2RDLABqcSGdZiIjPAkh7HEABgBBNc3JIawqe0wJgFVHAEkABQAlAHkdbAYGa8utl43hvCo947Or2/vH55vHZ7A4TKgGVisFyZYh4dwQdoTCbMBRGCBSSQYkDYjFGTBGEgATwxiKRAHoyRMAOKOI4THQTNBGLx4djECbQ4iw9xbJF8/kCwWCinI%2BaLAD6fmAtDY4qoWj6EBq6GxeIJxEJ4pIWGIkswAEdxcgau0XjtlEozbtMPsHGCIVCYXDiAiJuLxQARACy0ldfJFJFFqAWyHFBAQxEwzHQcoVmCVBBVIDVRK1xB1esNxoIpqBQ2sH1e6wI%2BK8whLUxmYxRCgmABVpisNnWJqxUNHxcxkPqDHhIwmk3Ng4tpjoG8sppIzAAPRHiADssjzHy%2BJwuNzuDyevL5LYIzMrHom04AdG3owPVfjU9r3OLI8Jp5h0Kahkv1vzldihyHJXhpbK8q0IqX7JteGpphmXY9n2mCvu%2B/IBuy4KQpy3IuvBSIfBMhLdBMADuIgEBMRATAYSgkQgcwTEYXbEKgO5IpGBA9LQJHMtM77DBamCMRMzGsceZ7tugl5geqmq3rq0G9pG8F8SKKGOlyzqupS7rer68l5gWVAvPOHpFiWzLloco7Vgotbjk26wAG6oHg6ATDUJCYPeyQovGoE/iOMzWZOM6kPWEy2Wwc6LlaK42t865/FugIfny3liqGUoyqwsbAV5iZXhJkF3g%2BUZKNpiXkpSgZKWhqklfyp4uf2oWsEFoEphBUnuY%2Bz4ldxrCWhsiGUpVTrwoi6mej6CKcRyNquRMZbMPYzlEJGfECcQbF1ct8aNc1OXiTe6YFR5xWcVaun6YZbwbMZ80VuZwiWfWjZbDUxAGKoEwMOcDA6OKPaYAYZkRf1ZF%2BKIzl4AAXm5BCEl4ZlDEeBi0Glz6nSD5H2MAIVsIDYZwwjR7jghS1zIsjJ0DUEPQ/j8PU4TEycKskjcOjmwg8lw5LDofg07D8ONhMCBRugbNIo1eP84cEuYOsXLiAArNIvO8QrhlvjunMhqOKu07xE4ZKyU0TCKi3MM5mBeJkcyHCwyDCwAtKwoJUPRRhCyLJGoPxz7vbbdAlvQARFkiLioPoc3kQgEBoCjxEy3rAUy7miULiTZX0sLyAANZgoG9HBnxsdU7rUuMj0kb0HWC2sIeJE18JF4teBkmHbqD7ME%2BL7GyKtDe6g4buARsIlsQtakYbTUTH3ExSVj0%2BYM%2BaMg0ixfEaXBML9OBDV6ydfIBXWg7zXk7SIzxsZwS6AQt7ShW8QNusISzne6WsPIto9qQsikYTPgNRY17AoKiLh2Anj4thCADht671rtMdWR5zwxhkrBCAwtoztBTkKH2LF1pgjYJaDWV1So40MLLeWSsD5ciPrAycCt6aKyPPA0hgMxZJS2h1Iq8ZJ5BWgcfVkNU%2BRrTYgQN6%2BsSYLkupsAybMtg3VMhycOtcvo/T%2BoDVhMx7AEEbNiLwUcY6U3jrjGGm8pBmGTpxfonRWAgH6ArfopBTD9FWA41AtidByDkC/HofRJxDE4A4ggtiXGYNINnEACtVhCFsdwBxTiXGkDcf0BxCgQBRKCc4qxpA4CwBgIgFAwYWRsnIJQJkRSqiZCMAATkkPkfYrBR6pIgC4YJDiXD2EyISWxATSBMjxPQa4tAn6tNIFgWioh2AjPwJGVItlMCpMyVYJ8B8SzdIcVo5QIznYuAfhqPQWA1mkFEXgIwazOg0HoEwNgHAeD8EEMIUQKBPEyCEHgFwqTICdFQF4IoCyHbXCGBMB2RhkB6PgWgLImBpwO2YJwexBQUhFE0NoeoeQrDaBaJUDw%2BRwj%2BDoKiwQuKiiYriFURoyRUh0BKHUfQuRqgUqKNSsoBxWhksULUbItKGjsuaCyrFHQug%2BJuaQQiAyfmnFoDQM50S7FxJGUk9YlwvQTGAMgZAEwqknkkCeTgEwoF0Dgnq3AhBAzDHyPSQprIh5msRB4mQchAmtNCeEyJMrYmkFOWYAAHCeL1CsFZVKGJISQqwhhDC9VUr1vB4muNsSktJRynXZLyWgkA3QCB6IICUgxzIrXYqsPgZaggLmMBYJM25%2BEH5eGlTY2Vjj5W2LNQRQgCAJiKuVaq9VmrtW6v1Q4dojrMmhPQTqSg1iYkONOf4nV3BuCrDMPOecVSzBmCZpwFd9bFlJPjekp1nQXVRNrUMOVW642JqHeO/okgT0JO3eekJnQ5ljwCCAbgQA%3D%3D) with zero barriers if you use `-DUNIPROCESSOR`, with `g++9.2 -O3 -mcpu=cortex-a15` (just to pick a random modern-ish ARM core so GCC can inline `std::atomic` load/store function and barriers for the non-uniprocessor case.